# How to resolve host (only) using Boost.Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query.html) of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query` in order to resolve host it should receive service
as well.

What if I want to resolve host without relation to port? How should I do it at all? Should
I specify dummy port?

Answer (score 7):

In [one post in the boost mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/03/149733.php) somebody else seemed to do it like this (copied, reformatted, service-number changed, nothing else):

```
namespace bai = boost::asio::ip;
bai::tcp::endpoint ep(bai::address_v4(0xD155AB64), 0); // 209.85.171.100:0
boost::asio::io_service ios;
bai::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);
bai::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(ep);
bai::tcp::resolver::iterator end;
while (iter != end)
{
  std::cerr << (*iter).host_name() << std::endl; // cg-in-f100.google.com
  ++iter;
}
```

As you correctly said, here a service is still passed in, but a step through the Boost.Asio code revealed this (in `resolver_service.hpp`, I'm using the rather old 1.36 release):

```
// First try resolving with the service name. If that fails try resolving
// but allow the service to be returned as a number.
```

So, just go with 0, and it should do what you want.

Comment: Take a not that you do use port number "ep(bai::address_v4(0xD155AB64), 80); // 209.85.171.100:80"

Comment: I slightly revised the example, hope it helps.